# "Itunesstored unexpectedly quit" in Xcode 9 simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9

While using Simulator in Xcode 9 I'm receving this alert box continuously "itunesstored unexpectedly quit".

[image]

Comment: I think its a bug in XCode 9GM, see this for ref https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87478